# Обмен файлами между nodejs сервером и react фронт-ендом?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно организовать обмен файлами, если сервер написан на nodejs, а фронт-енд на react (JavaScript).

Я Организовал отправку файлов на сервер с помощью `formData`. напихал в него несколько файлов и засунул в `body` с использованием `fetch`.
На сервер пришли файлы в виде массива буферов, а в body были указаны дополнительные данные.

Теперь пытаюсь получить файлы с сервера обратно. Делаю запрос. На сервере архивирую массив файлов, превращаю архив в буфер и делаю отправку на клиент вот так

```
const readStream = new stream.PassThrough();
readStream.end(response);
res.writeHead(200, {
'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=zip-archive.zip',
'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
});
readStream.pipe(res);
```

Тут `response` - это буффер архива как раз.
На клиент приходит какой-то странный ответ.

[image: Ответ от сервера на клиенте]
В `_proto_` -> `body` некий `ReadableStream`, а заголовков нет вообще.
**Как я могу сохранить полученный архив на диск?**

Скорее всего делаю что-то не так. **Объясните, а лучше приведите фрагменты кода на стороне сервера и клиента, чтобы было ясно.**

Уточню заранее, наименования файлов известны только серверу, так как хранятся там, а доп информация о файлах берется из БД при запросе.

Хотелось бы в идеале отправить на клиент также body с информацией о файлах и сами файлы.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь отправить архив, но смущает заголовок `'Content-Type': 'text/plain'`. Если используете `express`, то у response есть свойство `download`: `res.download('/path/example')`.

Comment: @Doigrales, я использую не express, а connect, так как сервер был гененрирован swagger-ом. Также я использую POST запрос.
Попробую указать **application/zip**